# ASP.NET session issues on a production server

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6, windows-server-2003, reportviewer

This is a pretty vague question as I've had no luck reproducing my issues outside of our production web server and am unsure if my two issues are even related.

My application server is running Windows Server 2003 and is public-facing. The ASP.NET web application runs in .NET 3.5 and uses a (private) SQL Server (2008) on the LAN. The server running SQL Server also hosts SQL Server Reporting Services which are used in our web app via a page containing a MS ReportViewer control.

The application used to run against .NET 1.1 and was migrated to 3.5 last year. The database was SQL Server 2000 and this was updated in a separate release early this year.

I've encountered two strange problems in our deployment that **must** be configuration-based, but I've run out of suspects.

Both problems relate to user sessions being lost.

The first occurs in reporting and is triggered in the ReportViewer control. Infrequently, our users will try to manipulate a report (I've found one reproducible case for a particular user and report combination - an exception is always thrown when I try to change report pages).

The exception call stack looks like this:

> Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.AspNetSessionExpiredException: ASP.NET session has expired or could not be found
>      at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ViewerDataOperation..ctor()
>      at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataOperation..ctor(Boolean requiresFullReportLoad)
>      at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.GetHandler(String operationType)
>      at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

The web app is configured to use InProc state storage, so a second IIS process wouldn't be able to locate the user's session - that's what this exception generally means, according to a few blogs I've read.
I could see IIS funneling additional requests to another worker process... Except the site is configured to use a single process. This exception shouldn't be thrown - so either the IIS GUI tools are lying to me about the web app being configured as single-process, or the exception message isn't describing the real problem.

I created a new application pool in IIS which is configured to recycle worker processes every 10000 requests and also at 2am. (The 10000 request rule is an old solution to resolve a problem that may or may not still exist - the problem and information on it predates me and I'm not inclined to experiment with it)
In the performance tab, the Max number of worker processes is set to 1.

The only fix I could come up with was to follow what the ReportViewer users have been saying, and that is to switch the state server mode from InProc to use an out-of-process serialization model. I chose the ASP.NET State Server.

It works just fine on every server except production. When I turned it on on production, every user had this experience:

1) Hit login page, enter credentials, log in
2) Click any link from home page
3) Booted back to log in screen. Re-enter credentials, log in.
4) The site now works normally until the user logs out.

Once again, this problem only existed on that production server and was not reproducible on my dev machine, our test server, or our public demo server.

Are they related? Maybe, maybe not. With so little usable diagnostic information I've been left with few ideas. If anyone's hit anything like this or has an idea of a new path I can go down I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve both issues.

The second issue (having to log in twice) was no longer reproducible. I did reregister ASP.NET (aspnet_regiis) while attempting another fix which **may** have fixed it, or another unrelated configuration change did it.

The primary issue is a bug in the ReportViewer control. For whatever reason, ASP.NET started logging more exceptions leading up to the one I reported and I got a hint of the root cause, which is outlined in this Connect issue:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/556989/blank-gif-resource-generates-server-error-in-reportviewer-in-non-ie-browsers?wa=wsignin1.0#tabs

I posted a workaround there as well. It's a bug in the web service that feeds the ReportViewer. The error was only being tripped by non-IE browsers.